# CSS Class not Working for Elements Inside other Elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style images inside of  links, but the classes that I give to the  tags are not styled according to the CSS style for the class. I was just wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to apply CSS styling to elements with classes inside other elements. Thanks! (P.S. I realize that it works on the code editor below, but on my webhost site (infinityfree.com) it does not work that way)

```css
p.tnc {
    text-align: center; 
    color: lightcyan; 
    background-color:#684c00; 
    padding: 3ch; 
    margin-top: 0cap; 
    font-size: large; 
    font-family: Verdana;
}
h1 {
    text-align: left;
    color: lightcyan;
    background-color:#684c00; 
    padding: 1ch; 
    margin: 0cap; 
    font-size: x-large; 
    font-family: Verdana;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font: bold;
    color:lightcyan;
    background-color:#684c00; 
    padding: 1ch; 
    margin: 0cap; 
    font-size: xx-large; 
    font-family: Verdana;
}

p {
    color:black;
    font-size: medium; 
    font-family: Verdana;
    font: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.info {
    text-align: left; 
    color: lightcyan; 
    background-color:#684c00; 
    padding: 3ch; 
    margin-bottom: 0cap; 
    font-size: medium; 
    font-family: Verdana;
    list-style-type: lower-greek;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.contact {
    color: lightcyan; 
}

.sample {
    width: 600px;
    max-width:100%; 
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="Original/angrywaspicon.png">
    <link href="tst.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>FP PHOTOS</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>FP Photos</h1>
    <h2>Photo Options</h2>
    <p class="tnc">ALL IMAGES ARE $6 AND COME IN 6x4 GLOSSY PHOTO PRINTS <br>Free Shipping on All Orders!</p>
    <div align="center">
        <a href="aw.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="gl.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="dl.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="wg.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="gddg.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="cu.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="gd.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="r.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="skm.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="tlfb.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="cjb.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
        <a href="fjb.html"><img class="sample" src="https://www.naturephotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/www.naturephotographie.com-an-autumn-dream.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    
    <ul  class="info">
        <a class="contact" href="mailto:fpphotostore@gmail.com"><li>fpphotostore@gmail.com</li></a>
        <a class="contact" href="tel:208-830-8555"><li>(208)-971-5260</li></a>
        <a href="sitemap.xml" class="contact"><li>Sitemap</li></a>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise ? What is exactly the problem ?

Comment: Your HTML markup is missing the closing tag for the <div align="center"> element.